# How to configure the proxy url inside Webpack.config.js after deploying the app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack, webpack-dev-server

On my local machine, my React front-end runs on `localhost:3000` and my Node/Express back-end 
runs on `localhost:8080`.

Inside `webpack.config.js` (for my front-end), I use proxy so my front-end can `fetch()` data from the back-end via the url `/api`

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  devServer: {
    proxy: {
      '/api': 'http://localhost:8080'
    }
  }
};
```

After I deployed my app to Pivotal cloud, the proxy configuration no longer works because it's set to `localhost`.

How should I configure it so that it's not hard-coded to localhost?

Answer (score 0):

[How to update React localhost (127.0.0.1:3000) to another domain (local.example.com)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58898600/how-to-update-react-localhost-127-0-0-13000-to-another-domain-local-example)

Might be too late on answer... First configure your hosts file to add local.example.com as your local envir(windows) see link

devServer has a host property

```
devServer: {
 host: 'local.example.com,
 port: 80
}
```

setting the port on 80 will allow you to visit http://local.example.com