# How to update React localhost (127.0.0.1:3000) to another domain (local.example.com)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, web-development-server

I am setting up a Localhost domain so it can communicate with this third-party API and Auth servers.
For example, change 127.0.0.1 to local.example.com

local.example.com is the domain whitelisted with this third-party enterprise. I need to set this up so i can run API routes to it.

I was able to change 127.0.0.1 locally in C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts file and now Node.js is running on it.

I added the webpack config devServer - host to local.example.com but the port is still there. I need to understand how to change this for react because right now it's porting to local.example.com:3000.

Answer (score 1):

A little late to the party but it still might be useful.

1. Go to `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` and add this line:

```
127.0.0.1       local.example.com
```

2. In the React project, add a `.env` file with:

```
HOST=local.example.com
PORT=3006
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're almost there :-) The `devServer` option has a `port` property. Set that to `8080` or `80`. Restart your server. Then, open the browser and try leaving it off the URL

Comment: THANK YOU! This definitely worked for HTTP. I am now trying to have this work for HTTPS but the results coming back is https://local.example.com:80. Would you have any idea to resolve this on HTTPS?

Answer (score -1):

After digging around, I found some solutions. Essential, my goal was to set http://localhost:3000 to http://local.example.com.

```
1. Add local.example.com to your hosts file (windows)
2. Set up your react port to 80
This would remove the 3000 on local.example.com:3000 to local.example.com

On HTTPS request, set the port to 443
This would result to https://local.example.com
```